# In a boolean matrix, what does the $n$ in $M_{R^n}$ represent?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, relations, boolean-algebra

I'm now learning about binary relations. I stumbled upon this question in the book:

> Given $A = \{1,3,5,6\}$ and $R$ is a relation over $A$, whose matrix
>   is defined by
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 &
>  0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Determine the smallest natural number $n$ such as $M_{R^n} = I_4$
>   [notice the $n$ next to $R$]
>
> Calculate $M_{R^{2006}}$

First of all, I don't know what does $M_{R^n}$ mean. What is $n$ supposed to represent? I don't know $I_4$ either, although I guess it means something like "index 4", referring to the fourth element in $A$ (6), but I'm just babbling.

Regarding $M_{R^{2006}}$, I guess I can find out by my own once I understand what is $M_{R^n}$ supposed to be.

The book says that the answer for the first question is that $n$ should be $4$. This doesn't quite help me.

Answer (score 1):

$R^n$ here is $R$ "applied" $n$ times, whose relation will then the $n$th power of the given matrix. The notation used is that the given matrix is $M_{R^1}$, the relation applied "only once." $M_R$ is a permutation matrix, and it is not difficult to see that $M_{R^k} = (M_{R^1})^k = I_4$ for some $k$, where $I_4$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix. Once you determine that $k$ you can easily calculate $M_{R^m}$ for any $m$.